# Can I format a pendrive after making it bootable

Tags: system-installation

If I make a pendrive bootable with Ubuntu 13.10, after installing can I format the pendrive and use it like before as a storage device?

Answer (score 3):

## How to change your bootable pendrive into a 'normal' pendrive

I don't think you need to reformat your pendrive. Just select all files and delete them. You might want to delete with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> so the space is really freed.

You can remove hte boot flag from your pendrive as to indicate the BIOS that it doesn't need to try to boot from it. You will need gparted for that, which isn't installed by default. To it from the terminal, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>. From there issue the command

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Once it's installed start gparted with sudo rights

```
sudo gparted
```

Gparted opens up showing you the partitions of your first drive. There is a combo-box in the top right, find for your pendrive. Once you've found it, right-click the partition and select `Manage flags` and un-check `boot`. Click `Close`. The changes take effect immediately.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can format the pendrive and use it like a storage device by formatting it to **FAT32** filesystem.Using **Gparted partition Editor** on ubuntu,you can Format the pendrive to FAT32 filesystem.